# How can I create a foreign key which references an entire composite key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables one has a three column composite key. The other needs to reference this composite key.

What is the syntax for creating a foreign key which references multiple columns.

I tried googleing, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
FOREIGN KEY (col1, col2, col3) REFERENCES ParentTable (colA, colB, colC)
```

Look under "`<table_constraint>`" in the online docs for Microsoft SQL Server [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(SQL.90).aspx).